# my add function doesn't give any error and it doesn't work too

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i made a panel to edit, delete and add products to sql database, but the add function doesn't work
here the codes:

**javascript**:

```
save : function () {

  adm.ajax({
    url : "ajax-products.php",
    data : {
      req : ("add"),
       id: document.getElementById("id1").value,
      name : document.getElementById("id2").value,
      category : document.getElementById("id3").value,
      price : document.getElementById("id4").value,
      something1 : document.getElementById("id5").value,
      something2 : document.getElementById("id6").value,
      description : document.getElementById("id7").value
    },
    ok : products.list //shows all prodcuts
  });
  return false;
},
```

**PHP**:

```
class Classname {
function add ($param1 ,$param2 , $param3, $param4 , $param5 , $param6 , $param7) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table 2` (`c1`, `c2`, `c3` , `c4` , `c5` , `c6` , `c7`) VALUES ($param1 ,$param2 , $param3, $param4 , $param5 , $param6 , $param7)";
try {
  $this->stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
  $this->stmt->execute();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo($ex->getMessage());
  return false;
}
return true;}}
```

**HTML Form**:

```
<form onsubmit="return products.save()">
  <input type="number" id="id1" required value="<?=$product['c1']?>"/>
  <input type="text" id="id2" required value="<?=$product['c2']?>"/>
  <input type="text" id="id3" required value="<?=$product['c3']?>"/>
  <input type="text" id="id4" required value="<?=$product['c4']?>"/>
  <input type="text" id="id5" required value="<?=$product['c5']?>"/>
  <input type="text" id="id6" required value="<?=$product['c6']?>"/>
  <input type="text" id="id7" required value="<?=$product['c7']?>"/>
  <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="products.list()"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

and i call the add function with this:

```
require PATH_LIB . "lib-products.php";
$classname = new classname();
echo $classname->add($_POST['id'] , $_POST['name'], $_POST['category'], $_POST['price'] , $_POST['something1'], $_POST['something2'], $_POST['description']) ? "OK" : "ERR" ;
```

when i wanna add a product for test, it doesn't give any errors and it doesn't works too

Comment: Where is the constructor ? And why classname is in double quotes?

Comment: In your query the variables that represent string needs to be single or double quoted like `VALUES ($param1 ,'$param2' , '$param3', $param4 , '$param5' , '$param6' , '$param7')`

Comment: no it doesn't help